Memory concerns in react-native-reanimated-carousel on iOS platform
I have implemented a screen which has multiple carousels (almost 10, 3 slides each), but these carousels on Ios are increasing memory usage of around 70~80 Mb in one minute. this only happens in autoplay on mode.
worst part is this incremented memory does not get release on unmount.
this happens only in ios, android garbage collects automatically
Any sugesttions are welcomed , what can I try
Thanks in advance.
what I have tried:
using the basic renderItem with no image, and basic implementation in an standalone project. No Improvement
used useRef, useMemo , useCallback, memo ,for optimisations, No Improvement
MyExpectations
there should be  no continuous memory increment

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
